# how to programmatically update customized DialogPreference layout, on dialog close action?

Tags: android

Trying to add a `TextView` on customized `DialogPreference` layout, I try to change this `TextView`'s text when dialog frame is closed and new value is save to the preference.

For this purpose I try to save Preference's root view overriding `onBindView` method:

```
@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    // saving reference to view of preference
    parentView = view;
}
```

and then, using it, update my `TextView` instance on `notifyChanged`:

```
@Override
protected void notifyChanged() {
    super.notifyChanged();
    if (parentView != null) {
        // finding target element
        View tagView = parentView.findViewWithTag("price_value");
        // setting new value to custom TextView
        ((TextView) tagView).setText(getText());
    }

}
```

However text does not updates until I switch fragment to other one, and then switch back to preference fragment from activity.

The code of changing fragment:

```
private void _loadMainFragment(Fragment mainFragment) {
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction =
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, mainFragment);
    mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    mFragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    mFragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Can anyone give me hint why TextView does not update first time, or where to dig in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was required to call:

`tagView.invalidate();
 tagView.requestLayout();`

On the view that should be updated.